# Memory usage in R during running a code

Tags: r, memory

I would like to check what is the top usage of memory during running a code in R. Does anyone know such a function?

The only thing I found, so far, is the function `mem_change` from `pryr` package, which checks memory change before and after running a code.

I work on Linux.

Comment: To analyse after code has run use `Rprof` or `Rprofmem`. If you are looking for real time memory use, I don't think there is anything in R.

Comment: `memory.size(max=TRUE)` returns pick usage during session. Start with fresh session, run your code and check this value.

Comment: Marek: memory.size and memory.limit are used to manage the total memory allocation on Windows. I should have mentioned that I work on Linux :)

Comment: There is also `ulimit` package on github, link to short vignette: http://krlmlr.github.io/ulimit/vignettes/ulimit.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gc()` will tell you the maximum memory usage. So if you start a new R session, run your code and then use `gc()` you should find what you need. Alternatives include the profiling functions `Rprof` and `Rprofmem` as referenced in @James comment above.